# Running contract code in javascript without deploying on chain

Tags: contract-invocation, truffle-deployment

I am building a state channel battleship game. I have a stateless contract which contains all my gameplay logic and another statechannels contract which contains all the dispute logic.

Ideally, I shouldn't be deploying either contract until there is a dispute.
To move through the game states, my contract accepts a `AppState` argument and applies the passed `Action` argument to return a new state. All my functions are pure.

Is there any way to run the contract code without deploying it on any chain?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for an abstraction of the Ethereum Virtual Machine for your smart contracts and you don't need to deploy them until something worth recording happens. At the same time, your game logic is in the form of smart contracts.

Check this out. [Ethereumjs-vm](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer's got to be [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/). JavascriptVM is the default simulation environment.